# Merging excel cells isn't works how its supposed to

Tags: vba, excel

mycode :-

```
Public Sub CombineCells()
  'Use to mash all cells with there contents into one

  Dim selectedCells As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim cellText As String

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  cellText = ""

  Set selectedCells = Selection
  For Each cell In selectedCells
    cellText = cellText & cell.Value & " "
  Next

  selectedCells.merge
  selectedCells.Value = Trim(cellText)
  selectedCells.WrapText = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Basically I want to merge cells from A1 to H6, `Range A1:H6`, into the same cell without losing the data in the cells (they are going to have the same number in every cell((like same value/)) when I run my code, it saves the date and merges the cells but the numbers are going like this

[image]

But I want it to be like this (merged into one cell and without the border.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Why are you merging cells at all?

Comment: its just for my homework(he just want us to write a macro that will merge cells without losing data)

Comment: ya i have edited it out,

Comment: Another tip: avoiding dimming variables with the name of existing objects (such as **cell** like you did here). I would change that to **mycell**. It doesn’t matter here, but later it may. If you are using the **cell** feature in excel, you may confuse either yourself of VBE with such naming methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant imagine why you would want to merge cells in such a way, but you were close none the less.

Since your range is static, define your range explicitly. Avoid `.Selection` & `.Select` when possible.

```
Sub Test()

Dim selectedCells As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellText As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
cellText = ""

Set selectedCells = Range("A1:H6")
For Each cell In selectedCells
    cellText = cellText & cell.Value & " "
Next

selectedCells.Merge
selectedCells.Value = Trim(cellText)
selectedCells.WrapText = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

You can find lists of cell appearance properties online or here is the first one Google pulled for me. [here](http://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-formatting-cells-and-values/)

You can use the With feature to quickly apply a bunch of formats to your range without having to continuously qualify the range

```
With selectedcells
    .Merge
    .Value = Trim(cellText)
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Comment: can i ask u another quesiton? do you the code on how i can increase a certain cell to be equal for the range rect like (A1 size equal to the size of range of A2:F2)
thank you for your help

Comment: thanks dude i will try,and thank you for your help earlier 
+1